# R plot dots distribution order

Tags: r, plot, colors

This is a question on the R plot. Let's say that have two classes in my dataset and I want to specify a colour for each class. Class one has 100 observations and class two has 1000. I want to have green colour for class one and blue colour for class two. I was wondering how can I have class one dots on top of class two dots (all green dots to be on top of the blue dots).

```
plot(dat$v1, dat$v2, col=ifelse(dat$class==1,'green','blue')
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```r
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(v1 = rnorm(1100), 
                  v2 = rnorm(1100), 
                  class = rep(c(1,2), c(100, 1000)))

with(subset(dat, class == 2), plot(v1, v2, col="blue"))
with(subset(dat, class == 1), points(v1, v2, col="green", pch=15))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>